# System.IO.PathTooLongException when path is way shorter

Tags: asp.net

I've seen this topic has been beaten to death but in my case .Net framework seems to be confused. I get the `System.IO.PathTooLongException` but the path is 151 characters long. I'm using UNC format with a fully qualified domain name of the shared folder which is 8 levels down from the root. The last folder has spaces in it which I would imagine should not affect things but I'm not sure.

I'm using a 4.0 framework, server is on the domain, user is trying to navigate to a location using HTML Input file type control. I'm using impersonation with a domain account who has at least read permissions to the remote share.

I also wanto point out that in my dev environment VS2010 it works fine - only happens when I publish it to test with a rescticted coporate sec policy.

Does anyone have an idea as why this error if path is way below the "too long" limit?

Comment: What OS is the server running you're trying to read from?

Comment: Please describe in more detail the code that throws the exception. A stack trace is the best way to understand where the problem is.

Comment: @CodeCaster: OS is Win2008.

Comment: @MartinLiversage:  I can't be sure since it works in Dev. It happens when I hit a button (not the browse button) whese event is trying to read the file using StreamReader.

Comment: @Risho: Your question is about the PathTooLongException so some part of your system is telling you that this exception is thrown. This exception also has a stack trace. In ASP.NET you can configure your site so that when an exception is thrown it is displayed in the browser ("yellow screen of death").

Comment: @MartinLiversage: The trace points to a onClick evnent where the files are read and operations performed. Overnight, I left the site on with the browse window open to the location and was able to sucesfully get the files and read/process them. But immedialtelly after that the process failed as described above. So I tried to upload the file that is at the root of the shared drive so path less then 20 chars and got the same error. Clearly it is a false positive so how can I get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @Risho: To get to the bottom of the problem a good strategy is to know the method call that fails and the parameters supplied. The best way to get this is to look at the stack trace of the exception. This will show the location and if code inspection at this point isn't enough you can add some logging just before the the offending method is called to discover the parameters. Knowing the name of the exception is most likely not enough to solve your problem.